# I'm using jdbc &hibernate to connect my DB oracle11gr2.I need to upgrade client libraries from hibernate 3.1.3 to 4.1.6

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g, hibernate3, hibernate-4.x

I need to upgrade my client libraries i.e hibernate from 3.1.3 to 4.x.I'm preferring 4.1.6.I have done upgrading jdbc 4 to 5 successfully.Now the problem is we are going to latest release from 3.1.6. I'm seeing  more than 250 errors.I'm bit confused in adding jars.I have added required folder from 4.1.6.Can some1 let me know should i add all the jars in required folder or just replace the jars present in my library

replaced:

antlr,
commons-collections ,
dom4j ,
hibernate jar.

I have tried both ways  adding all required jars folder  and just replacing the jars which are same with my library and 4.1.6. In both cases i'm getting same errors.

thanks for ur reply

Comment: try replacing all jar with the new ones, then clean and build the application. Be sure that you make the necessary changes such as adding extra description to web.xml etc. and if you still get errors, please share the specific error message so we can help you better.

Comment: The new jars may not be capable with any jar in your project. so make sure that your hibernate version is capable with other jars.

Comment: Hibernate 4 is NOT (fully) backwards compatible with Hibernate 3 -- especially 3.1.6, which still uses JPA 1.

Answer (score 0):

you should check the dependencies between jars in your project. you can use some tools like http://www.jboss.org/tattletale